# How to create ; in one's own created shell?

Tags: shell

I think I should separate three cases. If Its a command alone, with no input or output files.  One with an input files and another with an output file?

Comment: You should create one more case not to forget the father process

Comment: You should probably parse the command line based on the ; but you have to be careful to match the quotes to avoid strings with semicolons. Then loop over the various arguments processing each the same way you process a single command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you should separate it in 4 cases! You forget the father process! The father has to wait that the son process (that is to say the command you passed) is actually done to take control again.

My advice is to do add a waitpid for the father:

```
case 1:                                // ;
            p=fork(); //bacause the father is still running while the son is processing                     
            if(p==0){// you should add the father case
                return 0;                
            }else{                            //father
                waitpid(//the parameter to add)    
                output=0;
                input=0;
                execute=1;    
            }
            break;
```